# JQGrid,Retain formatter textbox values after search operation

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a textbox formatter column. When I perform search operation 
after entering something in the textbox, the textbox gets cleared. 
I want to retain the values in the textbox even after the search.
Here's my code:

```
colModel : [ 
   {name:'val',index:'val', width:40, align:'center',searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] } },
   {name:'id',index:'id', width:50,sortable:false,align:'center',edittype: "text",search:false,formatter:ctrlformat}            
]


function ctrlformat (cellvalue, options, rowObject ){       
return '<input type="text" id='+cellvalue+' name="valId" />';

    $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter:true});   
}
```

[image: grid with toolbar search, and colName "answer" with textbox]